# como alterar a cor do botao via codigo no android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Como trocar a cor do botão via a código, pois ao tocar no botão quero que ele troque a cor, a cor se encontra dentro do drawable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
seuButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_button_style);
```

Com este método, você vai atribuir ao `Background` do botão, um shape vindo XML com a sua cor/estilo desejado.

---

Mas com esta solução, você vai aplicar um filtro de cor sem precisar um XML-Drawable.

```
PorterDuffColorFilter colorFilter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
seuButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```

---

**mais em**: [PorterDuffColorFilter - Documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffColorFilter.html)

Answer (score 3):

Podes alterar a cor do botão assim:

```
Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botao);

botao.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
```

A cor tem de estar no `res->values->color_list.xml` nos *resources*:

```
<color name="Red">#FF0000</color>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use isso dentro do código **XML** do **Button** para mudar para a cor desejada:

```html
android:background="@android:color/(coloque sua cor aqui, exemplo: holo_blue_dark)"
```

Para mudar de cor sem ser por código *(mesmo que você não tenha perguntado isso, irei escrever para talvez ajudar quem precisa)* vá à Desing>Button>Background>Resources(reticências ao lado de Background), então é só clicar na cor escolhida.

Comment: A pergunta na verdade é sobre como mudar a cor do botão via código java. Ele quer mudar a cor no mouseover.