# Mudar a cor do FAB via código ( programaticamente )

Tags: java, android, floatingactionbutton

Estou desenvolvendo uma `Activity` personalizada, onde as cores dos elementos da tela vão variar conforme suas propriedades.

Exemplo: Se a propriedade **tipo** do objeto **Mensagem** exibida é `"Azul"`, então os seguintes elementos do arquivo `colors.xml` serão utilizados:

```
    <item name="azulFundo" type="color">#979dfd</item>
    <item name="azulTexto" type="color">#0011ff</item>
    <item name="azulFundoFab" type="color">#343b93</item>
```

Para isso, faço o seguinte no método `onCreate`:

```
          @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_mensagem_view); 

           mView = RelativeLayout.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.activity_mensagem_view)); 
           compartilharAction = FloatingActionButton.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.compartilharAction));
           imagemTipo = ImageView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.imagemTipo));
           textMensagem = TextView.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.textMensagem ));
           final String tipo = getIntent().getStringExtra(MESSAGE_TYPE);

          if("Azul".equals(tipo)){ 
              mView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.azulFundo)); 
              imageType.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseContext(), R.drawable.azulImagem));  
              textMessage.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor( getBaseContext(), R.color.colorAguaTxt) ); 
              compartilharAction.setBackgroundResource(R.color.azulTexto);

          }else...


      }
```

Tentei através do [setBackgroundResource](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51120/como-alterar-a-cor-do-botao-via-codigo-no-android), mas não funcionou!

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html):

> The background color of this view defaults to the your theme's
>   colorAccent. If you wish to change this at runtime then you can do so
>   via setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList).

Tradução direta:

*A cor de fundo dessa padrão [desta view](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) é o `colorAccent` do seu tema. Se você deseja alterar isso em tempo de execução, então pode fazê-lo através de `setBackgroundTintList` ([`ColorStateList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html)).*

Então veja como pode ser feito:

```
compartilharAction.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(
    ContextCompat.getColor(getBaseContext(), R.color.azulFundo)));
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito  obrigado!